# Strange error on running Shiny app remotely

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app which works adequately locally but produces the following error
when I try to process at
http://glimmer.rstudio.com/pssguy/acs/

"Error: trying to get slot "estimate" from an object of a basic class ("logical") with no slots"

The app page loads with no problem but clicking the action button produces the error

Anybody had experience of this and can point me in right direction
Could not find obvious answer on Google

cheers

Comment: Did you try the Shiny google group mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shiny-discuss)?

Comment: @Scott Yep. first port of call a day or so ago. No replies as of yet

Comment: I wonder if you are running R 3x on your machine. From what I understand Glimmer is still on R 2.15x and I think they aren't planning to upgrade to R 3x.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain's correct. I'd carefully check the version of R and the packages you're using locally/remotely. And/or you can use [packrat](https://github.com/rstudio/packrat) to manage your dependencies.

Comment: @Scott@Jeff. I am running R locally at 3.0.2 . The packages I am specifically loading for the app are all at the same version locally and remotely. All bar one depend on 2.15.3 or lower. The exception is choroplethr which I downloaded from github as it is not yet on CRAN. It does not mention an R dependency, just acs. So is this likely to be the issue. I will contact the developer as well but would appreciate your input

Comment: Update. I have put the app up on AWS EC2 which is running 3.0.2 and am getting same error